# Creating indexes on two columns to check if a date falls between those two

Tags: sql, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5, rdbms

I'm using Laravel 5 and postgres. There is a table which has two columns 'start_date' and 'end_date'. I want to create an index so that I can easily check if a date falls in between those two.

I'm using the following code to do that

```
$table->date ( 'start_date' );
$table->index('start_date');

$table->date ( 'end_date' );
$table->index('end_date');
```

But I saw that there is an option to create a compound index too.

My question is what is the best way to create indexes for my above scenario?

Comment: depends on data distribution and on the fact if you are always going to specify both column or not. if not, better index them separately. If you always have both columns in where, then two column index would be faster then two one column each.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what your queries are. While other databases like MySQL can use only one index per table in most situations postgresql can use more than one.

Thus if you have two separate indexes on start_date and end_date chances are they will both be used if the where close has conditions for both columns. Note that there isn't a guarantee that both indices or even one of them might be used. For example if you have only a few rows it would be much faster to retrieve the data directly without referring to the index. In this situation having a composite index wouldn't be of much use either.

If you have other queries that involve only one of the two columns, you are again better off with two separate indexes

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question - find a date between start/end range, what you want is an index on a (date) range-type.

You could use an actual `daterange` in your table definition, but it's not necessary, since PostgreSQL supports expressions in indexes.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (start_date date, end_date date);
INSERT INTO t1 SELECT '2001-01-01' + i, '2001-02-01' + i FROM generate_series(0,9999) i;
CREATE INDEX date_range_idx ON t1 USING gist (daterange( start_date, end_date) );
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE daterange(start_date,end_date) @> '2002-01-01'::date;
```

See the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html) for full details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was informative. But I'm thinking of only using the Laravel migration API right now.